# Mixed Content - Insecure Stylesheet

Tags: css, ssl, stylesheet

In the browser, I am receiving following error:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.website.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I found where the stylesheets are called in the code, and changed the address with https:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but without success, The error is still there.

Any help or suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `https` in a Google fonts link definitely *does* work - just empty the browser cache after changing the stylesheet link to

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone.
The problem is solved by replacing HTTP with https, but the problem was that the link was generated dynamically in the template.