# how to fix adapt.min.js file using createElement ? make bugs when the site use SSL

Tags: javascript, createelement, adapt

I use SSL in my site, I have this bug:

```
combine.js:6 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.******.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/archivonarrow/v3/DsLzC9scoPnrGiwYYMQXpp4t0mJKPaLVqklzZuc32b4.woff'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

combine.js:6 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.******.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/archivonarrow/v3/M__Wu4PAmHf4YZvQM8tWsHhM4mdXpoxYNWk7Ev34U70.woff'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

combine.js:6 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.******.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v6/zhcz-_WihjSQC0oHJ9TCYPk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

combine.js:6 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.******.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v6/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcoWiMMZ7xLd792ULpGE4W_Y.woff2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

all these erors comes from this line

```
!function(a,b,c,d){function m(a,b){l.href=e,f=e,h(a,b)}function n(){clearTimeout(g);var c,h,n,o,p,q,a=b.documentElement?b.documentElement.clientWidth:0,r=k,s=k-1;for(e=d;r--;)if(c=j[r].split("="),h=c[0],q=c[1]?c[1].replace(/\s/g,""):d,p=h.match("to"),n=p?parseInt(h.split("to")[0],10):parseInt(h,10),o=p?parseInt(h.split("to")[1],10):d,!o&&r===s&&a>n||a>n&&o>=a){q&&(e=i+q);break}f?f!==e&&m(r,a):(m(r,a),e&&(b.head||b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).appendChild(l))}function o(){clearTimeout(g),g=setTimeout(n,16)}if(c){var e,f,g,h=c.callback||function(){},i=c.path?c.path:"",j=c.range,k=j.length,l=b.createElement("link");l.rel="stylesheet",l.media="screen",n(),c.dynamic&&(a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener("resize",o,!1):a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent("onresize",o):a.onresize=o)}}(this,this.document,ADAPT_CONFIG);
```

my site use SSL, and the urls must be https
I need to fix it please and i dont know anythings about .js just i made combine for all .js file

I add the bug here
[adapt.min.js SSL bug](https://github.com/nathansmith/adapt/issues/33)
how to use https in createElement ?

Comment: Hi have you tried changing your asset's URLs to `https`?

Comment: if you mean the main urls of the site, yes i made the change so all the links in my site work with https.

Comment: No I meant your font's URLs such as `http://fonts.gstatic.com`? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content?hl=en

Comment: the thing is I couldn't find this url !, i thought its from the .js file ^_^

Comment: i couldn't find this url, how to add https to createElement("link")

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error
You will see that it has been corrupted for **HTTPS**. This means that
You should not use HTTPS where you called your site.
Please change **HTTPS** to **HTTP** and tell me if you got another error

And that you can find out more about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368233/mixed-content-insecure-stylesheet)

Comment: the problem is my site run SSL, I use vbulletin 3

Comment: i think problem is in your theme it was nested inside the theme in location.

Comment: @AbdulmohsenAlmadi  try this plugin in vB. https://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?p=2589795#post2589795

Comment: thanks @Ali Ghaemi , I'm using vbulltein 3, also use BDTech - vB Optimise, i tried to disable it but didn't work

Comment: I mean VB. is the same as vbulltein

Comment: its different between visions lol , vb 4 plugins doen't work on vb 3

Comment: I'm sorry I did not look at 3 at all.

Comment: check this createElement("link")

Comment: where can I find it !?

Comment: your second box you added in your question . you can find j=c.range,k=j.length,l=b.createElement("link")

Comment: what must I do exactly ? how can I edit it, this is the js code. it cause the bug!

Comment: how to add https into createElement

Comment: This error message says that
You are trying to mix two HTTP HTTPS  together check your jsCode

Comment: ask again your question or give your question bounty.